# Enumerate sql express servers

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've got SQL Server 2008 Express installed twice with 2 instances. The first is the default SQLExpress and the second I named. We'll say TestExpress. I know if I go into the registry under SQL Server it list both of these instance names and I can probably retrieve this information from 
there. But is there anyway to retrieve it via SQLDMO or any of the .NET SQL references.

I turned on SQL Server Browser, i used almost all the code that i can find on internet (yeah, i did it ) but all of them  retrieve 2 items: {local} and my computer name

I also checked that the server instances are not Hidden.

I don't want to use SMO, because I have plans for SQL Server express 2005 and 2008 . Using a specific version of SMO will not allow me to work with both the versions.

Comment: Why do you have two instances of the same program installed?  Why don't you simply have two databases?

Comment: @Ramhound. thats part of the scenario,the client wants.. the databases are replicated ( i belive) so that in case , one goes down, they can connect to the other database on the other server by just changing the connection string.. they want to play clever by playing it safe... :|

Answer (score 0):

what .NET code have you tried so far?

I'm getting good results with this snippet:

```
  System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
  System.Data.DataTable dataTable = instance.GetDataSources();
  foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(row["ServerName"] + "\\" + row["InstanceName"]);
  }
```

Comment: I am getting blank lines :(.. and although I am getting the server name , I am not getting the instance name .. i tried that code already .. what I am doing now is getting it from the registry.... for the local server.. for the remote server, i ask the user to enter the instance name .. although I fail to understand why I am not getting the instance name .. i tried with sql browser turned on as well..